# Tab with Table - can I edit the layout or styling of the tab with table vier

Tags: custom-fields, forms, display

Can I modify the layot of the Tab With Table "view"?
So I have created a form using custom data fields, and selected the Tab with Table view.  This works fine except when I look at a completd form using the "View" function.  It renders in a pretty horrible looking table - see attached image.  I'd like to be able to edit the layout/format of the View to make it a litle more uesr and print friendly.  Is this possible?

[image: Tab With Table]

Comment: I don't understand why your table looks like that. Just looking at it I can't even tell how many custom fields you have, what they are called and how many rows you have. Can you give a bit more info on that?

Comment: Hence my question!  This is a tab with table view of a set of custom fields that is like a survey of sorts. It looks fine in jsut the normal view but when I go to tab with table it gets all messed up and I cannot see any way to modify the layout of the view.  What sort of specific info do you require to look into this some more?

Comment: If you looko at question 1 in the image, the answer is diesplayed immediatley to the right.  For question 2 i am guessing/hoping it would create a new row below question 1 (as per a table) butit appears to be nesting each subsequent answer in a row or cell below the answer of the previous question.

Comment: The tab-with-table layout is supposed to be in columns - questions at the top (table header row) and answers below each question. What version of CiviCRM are you using and do you have any extensions or template overrides on your site?

Comment: I'm using CiviCRM 4.7.11, no templates, but I have installed 2 extensions for reports being Civisualize and  ExtendedReport but this issue was happening before I installed them.